# Component should return same value wherever it's called. and Main Component should not rerender when Sub Component useState is updating in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I want same value in Home function from Component and Home function should not rerender when Component useState is updating.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Component() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("rerender")
  })
  useEffect(() => {
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
      setCount(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000))
    }, 1000)
    return () => clearInterval(interval)
  }, [])
  return count
}

function OtherStuff() {
  console.log("OtherStuff")
  return (<h1>Should Not Rerender OtherStuff</h1>)
}

function MoreStuff() {
  console.log("MoreStuff")
  return (<h1>Should Not Rerender MoreStuff</h1>)
}

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <h1>
        <Component />
      </h1>
      <OtherStuff />
      <MoreStuff />
      <h1>
        <Component />
      </h1>
    </>
  );
}
```

I have called Component function two times, I want same value should render to both from Component.
and when ever Component {count} is update by using setCount, Main function should not rerender. at this time, there is no rerender for Component in Main function which is OK.
this is the simple problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Each instance of a component has its own state. Meaning their states are not shared. If you wanna share the state between them, one way would be to lift the state up. If you do not want the `Home` to rerender, you cannot move the state to `Home`. So you probably need another component which holds the state. You can use react context to do so. Wrap your instances of `Component` inside a context provider which holds the `count` state and provides `count` and `setCount`.

Comment: I think you are saying me to do which is in this link https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-surf-mj6z8n?file=/src/App.js but this is not working. it's rerender the `Home` component

Comment: I posted an answer and tried to explain it more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each instance of a component has its own state. Meaning their states are not shared. If you wanna share the state between them, one way would be to lift the state up.

If you do not want the `Home` to rerender, you cannot move the state to Home. So you probably need another component which holds the state. Because any component which has a react `useState` hook, will be rerendered when the state is updated.

You can use react context to do so. Wrap your instances of Component inside a context provider which holds the count state and provides count and setCount.

First you need to create a context:

```
const CountContext = createContext();
```

Then create a component which provides the context and holds the state:

```
const CountProvider = (props) => {
  // `useCounter` uses `useState` inside.
  const [count, setCount] = useCounter();
  return (
    <CountContext.Provider value={{ count, setCount }}>
      {props.children}
    </CountContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

(OP provided a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-dirac-9rpenz?file=/src/App.js) which uses `useCounter` custom hook. It stores a number to `count` state and updates it to a random number every 1000ms.)

Then wrap it around your components:

```
function Parent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <CountProvider>
        <Counter />
        <Counter />
      </CountProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-dirac-9rpenz?file=/src/App.js)

Note that:

1. If you render another component inside `CountProvider` using `children` prop, it will NOT rerender every time `count` state updates, unless it uses the context.
2. But if you render a component inside `CountProvider` and render it in the function, it WILL rerender, unless you use `memo`.